# Native JavaScript validaton of form inputs in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have been learning with JSF not even for a weak, so I am very new to this. I have already found one "problem"...well, it's not actually a big deal, but more a cosmetic problem.

I have made basic form to register users with some validation tags (see code above). Everything works fine, but I would also like to use client side control via JavaScript. I have already found that I can write my own JavaScript check function - but that's not what I would like to have. I already defined validation rules in the validation tags, that's why I think it is stupid to write the code manually, when such a nice framework like JSF is able to do most of these things automaticly. I have also found out that Sun has purposely removed JavaScript auto validation from JSF.

So my question is: Is there any way how to make JSF generate JavaScript functions (with f:validate info) using them automaticly on form submit? Also, I use PrimeFaces, is it possible to achieve this using PrimeFaces?

Here is code of the form I have made:

```
<h:form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="registration-email">#{usersTexts.email}:</label></th>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{userRegistry.newUser.email}" id="registration-email" validatorMessage="#{msg.invalidEmail}" maxlength="100">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$" />
                </h:inputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="registration-name">#{usersTexts.name}:</label></th>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{userRegistry.newUser.name}" id="registration-name" validatorMessage="#{formsTexts.field} #{usersTexts.name} #{msg.isEmpty}" maxlength="100">
                    <f:validateRequired />
                </h:inputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="registration-password1">#{usersTexts.password}:</label></th>
            <td>
                <h:inputSecret value="#{userRegistry.newUser.password}" binding="#{password}" id="registration-password1" validatorMessage="#{formsTexts.field} #{usersTexts.password} #{msg.isEmpty}">
                    <f:validateRequired />
                </h:inputSecret>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="registration-password2">#{usersTexts.passwordAgain}:</label></th>
            <td>
                <h:inputSecret id="registration-password2" validatorMessage="#{msg.passwordsNotEqual}">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="#{user.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH}" />
                    <f:validator validatorId="equality" />
                    <f:attribute name="matchAgainst" value="#{password}" />
                </h:inputSecret>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <p:captcha immediate="true" validatorMessage="#{msg.wrongCaptcha}" requiredMessage="#{formsTexts.captcha} #{msg.isEmpty}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="submit_row"><h:commandButton value="#{usersTexts.register}" action="#{userRegistry.register}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSF spec doesn't define or offer any native JavaScript validation.

If all you want is immediate feedback, just put an

```html
<f:ajax event="blur" render="messages" />
```

inside the input fields in question and an

```html
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
```

inside the command buttons.

Comment: That actually does not work...on submit I get this error: malformedXML: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE), and on blur nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` in the template? The `<h:head>` allows JSF (and component libraries) to auto-include the necessary CSS/JS files.

Comment: Yes, I do. Actually it was just in the template, not in the concrete page, but thats not problem...tried to add <h:head> to there too and the problem remains.